# How do I scale volumetric clouds in Eevee so it looks like the camera is falling through the sky?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

Camera is pointed up towards sky, and I cannot seem to get the clouds to scale down enough to make the camera look like it's falling. Here are shots of where the volumetric box starts and stops, in addition to the cameras pov. Node setup is also included, keyframed to move from left to right and change cloud shape. I've played around with scale in mapping, but it doesn't help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nMMl.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]